# How does my Exception object have a bunch of different properties at runtime that aren't there at devtime?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a global exception handler that gets the `System.Exception` object as depicted below.

What you see when I inspect the object at runtime is the list of properties that appear to be in the `Exception` object.

[image]

But if I attempt to refer to some of the properties at dev time, e.g. `Content`, we can see that the property isn't there anymore.

[image]

Can someone explain what is going on here? Is it possible for me to refer to the `Content` property at dev time? If so, how?

Comment: Is the type of the exception a subclass of Exception which has more properties? Maybe you could print out the type of it at runtime to see ( exception.GetType() ) and then cast it to that type to access that property at devtime?

Comment: What is the actual type returned by `exceptionHandlerPathFeature.Error`? I assume it has the properties that you're referring to, which will still show up in the details window that you included. But since `exception` is declared as a `System.Exception`, those properties won't be available on the actual instance unless it's cast back to the original type.

Comment: good idea @Ideae, that gave me the info I need. I could see with `exception.GetType()` that the type returned is `{Name = "ApiException" FullName = "Refit.ApiException"}` and casting to that got me the devtime properties that I need. If you want to write that into an answer I'll accept it for you.

Comment: Yep just posted it as an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception object is likely a subclass of the Exception type which has more properties. You could print out the type of the exception object at runtime using

```
exception.GetType()
```

and then cast it to that type to access that property at devtime:

```
if (exception is ApiException) {
  var apiException = (ApiException)exception;
  var context = apiException.Content;
}
```